# Failed to fetch : Error while installing apache web server on ubuntu

Tags: docker, apache, ubuntu

I was trying to build a docker image. While running the installation command for apache web server from the Dockerfile, an error popped up.

[image]

Note : I have already added the space between -y and apache2-utils in the actual file.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/tzdata/tzdata_2021a-0ubuntu0.20.04_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-bin_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-data_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.4_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2-utils_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.41-4ubuntu3.4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/ca-certificates/ca-certificates_20210119~20.04.1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y apache2' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

I tried running the update command and built the Dockerfile again but it error persisted .

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]. And make sure you don't need a proxy to access the internet (or configure it).

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your example using the Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER "me"
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y apache2-utils
RUN apt-get clean
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

and then running `docker build .`

I did not perceive the network issue you had but the installation became interactive:

```
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

So you may want to

- rerun your code
- ensure apt-get will not get interactive

One last remark: The `apt-get clean` will not make your image smaller at all. Every `RUN` adds a filesystem layer, and it means you would add a layer telling it to hide files. To prevent that, chain your calls to `apt-get` into one single `RUN` line like this:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 && apt-get install -y apache2-utils && apt-get clean
```